# Shareable post url from facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sharing

I'm building an app that gets its data from from facebook graph api like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts?fields=id,from,message,message_tags,story,story_tags,link,source,name,caption,description,type,status_type,object_id,created_time,full_picture&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

How do I get a url to the post that can be shared?

**link** only works for shared content

**id** returns USERID_POSTID

Constructing the following url manually works, but it can't be shared:

`https://www.facebook.com/USERID_POSTID`

Sharing requires the following format:

```
https://www.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts/POSTID
```

Is it possible to get the post url in the correct format directly from the feed or do I have to split up the **id** and construct the url manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a graph api variable permalink_url that returns the full post url.